# Fade in background image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, fadein

This is the first time I am using jQuery. I am loading a large background image and when it is loaded I am fading it in over three seconds. This script works on Firefox and Chrome but not in IE (of course!). Is there any fail safe way of making it magically work in IE and is there some prettier way of writing it?

```
<div class="bgImage" />
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // add bg image and fade
  var _image = new Image();
  _image.id = 'newImageId';
  _image.src = "./css/background.jpg";

  $(_image).load(function () {
    $('div.bgImage').css('background-image', 'url(./css/background.jpg)');
    $('div.bgImage').fadeTo(3000, 1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Try `return false` - this stuff is important in IE. Plus could you not use global vars, use like `var = _image.id` and `var = _image.src`?

Comment: You should not use `var` when assigning to an object, like `_image.src = ...`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use

```
 $('div.bgImage').animate({ opacity: 1 }, { duration: 3000 });
```

assuming you are starting of with `style="opacity: 0;"`

Comment: yes it will. im sure for ie 8. not that sure for lower versions

Comment: I have tried it but it did not work. I have added an alert in the load function and that one is never triggered in IE.

Answer (score 2):

### HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="bgImage"></div>
  ...
</body>
```

### CSS

```
.bgImage {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

### Javascript

```
$(function() {
  var src = '../css/background.jpg';
  var ele = $('.bgImage');
  var img = $('<img>', {
    src: src
  }).hide().appendTo(ele).load(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    ele.css('background-image', 'url('+src+')').fadeIn(3000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for this you dont need to write that many lines of code this simple code will work for u...

```
$(document).load(function () {
  $('div.bgImage').css('background-image', 'url(./css/background.jpg)');

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.bgImage').fadeIn(3000);
  });
});
```