# Fade in a changed div background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the following js to change the `background-image` on a div but I would like to fade in the image.  How can I do that?

```
    var now = 0;
    var int = self.setInterval("changeBG()", 3500);
    var array = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", ];

    function changeBG(){
        //array of backgrounds
        now = (now+1) % array.length ;
        $('.documentary').css('background-image', 'url("' + array[now] + '")');
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227901/fade-in-background-image-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css animation. 
in documentary place something like that:

```
-webkit-transition-property: background-image 300ms ease-in 200ms;
-moz-transition-property: background-image 300ms ease-in 200ms;
-o-transition-property: background-image 300ms ease-in 200ms;
transition: background-image 300ms ease-in 200ms;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it transparency you are looking for?

You can use `opacity` on the div containing the image, but this will also make everything inside transparent as well.

Or you could make the image transparent to begin with.