# Hover on element, fade in background on parent div

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, transition, fade

I have an »element« on a fullscreen div. I want to hover on the »element« and **fade** in a background-image in the div ».section«. It's no problem to just show the background-image but I have no idea how I add a fade-animation.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.element').hover(function() {
    $('.section').css('background-image', 'url(https://ih0.redbubble.net/image.87373734.8395/flat,800x800,075,t.jpg)');
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background
    $('.section').css('background-image', '');
  });
});
```

```css
.section {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 1s ease all;
}

.element {
  margin-top: 45%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
 <div class="element">hover me</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sr1qj1pc/

Could you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fade in background image with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227901/fade-in-background-image-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle.

You can use CSS alone no need to use jquery. You can use a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) to get the effect that you want.

In this case, if you hover the children element which is the `.element` then display the background of the parent which is the `.section` you can use `pointer-events` which specifies under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse events. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

CSS:

```
.section {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 1s ease all;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.section:after {
    background: url(https://ih0.redbubble.net/image.87373734.8395/flat,800x800,075,t.jpg) repeat;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* TRANSISITION */
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.section:hover:after{   
    opacity: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sr1qj1pc/3/

Comment: thank you but that's not what i want. i want to hover on the div ».element« and fade in the background of the div ».section«

Answer (score 0):

Another quick approach -

```
   $(function() {
  $('.element').hover(function() {
    var section =  $('.section');
    section.fadeOut(0, function(){
        section.css('background-image', 'url(https://ih0.redbubble.net/image.87373734.8395/flat,800x800,075,t.jpg)');
        section.children().fadeIn();
        section.fadeIn(1500);
    });
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background
    $('.section').css('background-image', '');
  });
});
```